# Mikro C pwM1_Set_Duty definition

Tags: microcontroller, pic

From where I can find definition of this function PWM1_Set_Duty actually I am trying to customize this function for some reasons. I want to access his code, from where I can ?

Comment: If it's function included with the compiler, then you're out of luck, it's closed source. Also which type of Mikro C are you exactly using? For which microcontroller and what is it that you really want to do?

Comment: I am using mikro c pro for PIC18f452 and I want to produce PWM at port B.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking in this question not possible in MikroC. It is Mikroelektronika's [policy not to provide source code for library functions](http://www.mikroe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=45596). Such is life when you're using closed-source tools.

The closest you can go is to start a project, compile it, look at the assembly code of the function and try to do something with it.

As for the comment, well I managed to build the PWM example with PIC18f452 selected and t built fine, but I don't have one available to test if it's actually working.